# Calculating Expected Value of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Question:

In a trip there are $n$ pairs of students. In total, there are $2n$ students. They were divided across n rooms in a hotel where each pair is in the same room. Because of a problem the $2n$ keys for the rooms were sent randomly.

Let $X$ be a random variable for the number of pairs of students who receive the correct key to their assigned room.
Calculate $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$.

---

For the second requirement, I see a law which fits perfectly for this condition. But in order to use it, I need to find $E(X)$ first.

Let's define an indicator $A_i$ which denotes the pair $i$ that receives at least one correct key, then:

$X$=sum of all possible $A_i$'s.

We have $E(x)$=$E($sum of all possible $A_i$'s$)=$sum of $E(A_i$ for each $i)$

**Please help. Thanks.**

Comment: I just got an idea, Maybe defining the following indicator will help? $A_i$ person $i$ got the correct key?

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea.  But remember that "success" just requires that at least one out of the two gets the right key.

Comment: @Lulu what do you mean, please see my first try (coming in few minutes)

Comment: Ah, I may have misunderstood the problem.  If $X$ is the number of students who gets the right key then you are correct.  I thought the problem was asking how many of the pairs of students are able to get into their assigned room, which is different.

Comment: @Lulu but your idea seems correct.... I mean then why we were given that each 2 share the same room. something seems to be wrong.

Comment: I'm stuck on how to calculate  (). (For the second case where only one in each partner is enough to have correct key)

Comment: Well, it seems weird to me that they go to all the trouble of telling us all about the students being paired up for rooms for no reason.

Comment: it seems to be a problem with translation, will check it out. please read my previous comment

Comment: In order for a pair of students to be able to get in, there are two cases:  either both students get the right key or one of them gets the right key and the other gets the wrong key.  Just do those cases separately.

Comment: I know that these are the only cases but I don't know what to do exactly

Comment: I don't understand.  Say the two students in room $1$ are $s_1, s_2$.  What is the probability that $s_1$ has the right key?  Given that $s_1$ has the right key, what is the probability that $s_2$ also has the right key?

Comment: But that depends on the order, for example after we finish with pair one pair 2 has less options of key to choose from so the probability changes

Comment: Remember, you are using Linearity of Expectation here.  We can ignore the dependence between the pairs and just work with a single pair.  That's the beauty of this technique.

Comment: so P(Ai) = (1/2n)*(1/{2n-1}) + 2*(1/2n * (2n-1)/(2n)). I should keep the 2 right? from there how I get E(Ai)?

Comment: No...We can ignore the dependence between the rooms, but not between the two students in a single room.The probability that they both get the right key is $\binom {2n}2^{-1}$.  Now try to compute the probability that $s_1$ gets the right key but $s_2$ gets the wrong key.

Comment: that's what I did

Comment: Then I don't understand how you got $\left(\frac 1{2n}\right)^2$ for the first case.

Comment: Oh right fixed it, now is it right? P(Ai) = (1/2n)*(1/{2n-1}) + 2*(1/2n * (2n-2)/(2n-1))

Comment: No.  I already gave you the answer for the first case,  it is $\binom {2n}2^{-1}$.

Comment: why? s1 has one option from 2n and s2 has one option from 2n-1 keys too....

Comment: No.  There are two keys that open door $1$.

Comment: Oh I didn't calculate P(Ai) but the number of combinations... can you write a brief answer for this part I am totally confused now

Comment: Perhaps you will find it weasier to think of the opposite problem.  There are $2n$ keys in total, $2n-2$ are not for door $1$.  Thus the probability that both kids get bad keys is $\binom {2n-2}2\big / \binom {2n}2$

Comment: But you should remove internal order so you answer should be divided by 2

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  I suggest you work it out explicitly for the case in which $n=2$.

Comment: So last answer is: what you said + 2*(2/2n + (2n-2)/(2n-1))?

Comment: You lost me,  The "last answer " to what?  The probability that the students in room one can open the door?  That's $1-\binom {2n-2}2\big/ \binom {2n}2$, as I said.

Comment: @Lulu why? you said at first it's "No. I already gave you the answer for the first case, it is (22)−1" then I added the option were only one has correct key....

Comment: Please try to follow the comments.  I gave you two ways to proceed.  The second (which I think you might prefer) is to go backwards.  As the probability that both kids get the wrong key is $\binom {2n-2}2\big/ \binom {2n}2$, the probability that at least one gets the correct one is $1-\binom {2n-2}2\big/ \binom {2n}2$

Comment: I suggest:  work it out completely for $n=2$.

Comment: I am talking about the first method, plus your solution is wrong "s the probability that both kids get the wrong key is (2−22)/(22)" since the first has n-2 wrong of n and the other n-3 of n-1

Comment: I suggest:  work it out completely for $n=2$.  Compare to my formula.

Comment: I already explained you the solution the first person has n-2 wrong out of n and the other has n-3 wrong of n-1 so (n-2)/n * (n-3)/(n-1)

Comment: So, if $n=2$ the answer is $0$?  But, enough.  I won't argue with you.  Good luck.

Comment: if would be much easier if you wrote an answer and let me ask what I don't understand.

Comment: @Lulu why 0? it's 1 minus what I wrote which is 1- 0 = 1

Comment: I suggest: read my comments again you didn't understand my solution

Comment: For the simpler problem of $N$ students, each in one of $N$ rooms with $N$ randomly assigned keys, you need to enumerate the [partial derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers). When you consider the pairs of students, I think the problem becomes nontrivial, see [this article about choosing sock pairs](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/2/Cockburn-MathMag-2014.pdf)